# How to properly block a div with a loading animation

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax function that I am calling.  While the Webserver is churning away on the Assynchronous request I want to block the div the user is view so he doesn't press any buttons or anything while that request is going on... I have done this before, and you simply would pick the dive you want to block with an animation, call .block and then when values successfully return you would simply unblock.  Like so...

```
function animateSpinner() {
    $("#list").block({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' });
};
```

and then simply call

```
$("#list").unblock({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' });
```

once you successfully return.
however, I am getting this exception whenever I attempt to do this...[image]

That is for the unblock part of it.  Which I forgot to comment out (I was simply testing the ajax portion of this.
Should these kind of calls be wrapped in a document.ready or something to ensure that they should be called.  I recently have had issues with ajax submits not working because they were not wrapped in $(document).ready calls and I would like to see if this is another instance of when something should be wrapped in that call?

Comment: First mistake is using IE to test anything, second mistake is that there is no method in jQuery called block or unblock.

Comment: There is no jQuery method `block` or `unblock`. See: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=block What are you trying to do? Where do you get those function names from?

Comment: Are you thinking of blockUI? That's a jQuery plugin documented here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/ - but there's no jQuery function called block(), so it's not surprising that you're getting an error.

Comment: Well, I find that quite surprising.  This is what I get for pulling week old code and just expecting it to work.  Maybe I have a block function hidden in one of my old jquery libraries that I was using.  Thanks.  Also, I appreciate the down votes as it acknowledges my rank stupidity.

Comment: Turns out I did have BlockUI in that project.  Can't figure out where I am putting it into my project however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments there is no such function as `block` on JQuery. You should use the `beforeSend` function in your AJAX request to set `disabled=true` for the buttons, or change the div's `z-index` to a negative value

Answer (score 1):

As @AmericanUmlaut pointed out you are using the jQuery BlockUI Plugin syntax. The example here http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element is near identical to what you are trying to do.,

As far as being concerned about onDOMReady as long as the BlockUI Plugin is loaded before the ajax calls in question start firing, you shouldn't have to do anything special to make this functionality work as expected